# Google search traffic sharp drop in clicks

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-index, traffic

My site is quite large and has a lot of indexed pages. 75% of my traffic comes from Google Search clicks and has remained quite consistent for most of this year.

Two weeks ago I noticed considerably smaller numbers on the site for a few days, this has continued and is still happening.

Nothing has changed* on the site and Google Webmasters has no notices or messages for me.

* = I know *something* has changed. I'm referring to things within my control changing; theres been no patches, no updates, no new or old traffic, etc.

I've been quick to fix any issues in the past that Webmaster Tools have suggested and any issues from DFP are resolved immediately.

The **only** issue that I can think of is my sitemap submissions, regularly seeing '0 sitemaps' when I log in, then next time I see the proper sitemaps. This has been the norm all year though.

**Some graphs**;

Pages crawled seems to have dropped a smidge.

[image]

Search clicks is the killer. Only 2 weeks ago it was ~210,000.

[image]

Probably the most telling graph is the sharp drop in the number of indexed pages.

[image]

Comment: You do know that Panda 4.2 is out? Many site owners are seeing hits from Google since this March, May, July, and so on with Quality Update, Newsy-Trend Update, Panda, and more. I rather suspect that Google is over optimizing the SERPs and punishing sites that are ligit. This would not be the first time. G has a long history of these over-reaches that I was hoping was over. I could list some of them if G has forgotten and needs a reminder.

Comment: Thanks @closetnoc - is this something that has been seen recently for other sites is it?

Comment: There have been a bunch of performance changes since last spring that seem to be unwarranted. I personally got hit by the June 17th Newsy-Trend Update which took half of my traffic. People are complaining that ligit sites are falling off the face of the earth in the past month or so. Meanwhile, blogs with short no Duh(!) content are still being rewarded and trends sites such as celebrity sites also being rewarded. Meanwhile, static research sites are being hit as well as personal professional sites, and other simple sites that should not set the search world on fire but perform well enough.

Comment: It is. No one really knows what is going on. But if you read the first few comments here: https://www.seroundtable.com/google-panda-42-reversed-20837.html you will see a sample of what I am seeing. I did a quick survey one day and there seemed to be some fluctuations and down-turns that I wondered about. I think people are as confused as I am. I guess we will just have to wait to see if G reverses course of explains some of this stuff. My personal opinion is that there are too many updates too close together to make sense of and correct.

Comment: Just read that link. The dates and behaviour definitely seem to correspond with my traffic turndown.

Comment: Interesting huh?? I am very supportive of Google because from a technical stand-point, they are tops and has never stopped working on creating a great search engine. I am pro-Google. However, there have been times that Google has screwed the Panda (That's a joke son! - Leghorn Foghorn) by having an idea and getting carried away with it resulting in over-optimization. I am getting the impression that this spring/summer updates are a carpet bombing of over-optimizing the SERPs rewarding trendy sites, popular sites, and punishing sites that Google generally does not like but are perfectly valid.

Comment: OP, Have you searched for keywords that apply to your site? chances are other sites rank higher than your sites and those that rank higher generally get more clicks. Maybe your site needs richer content?

Comment: Hi @Mike I am not sure we'd see such a sharp drop if it was keywords related. I went from ~1.4m pages in the index to ~920k in a few days. I just don't think that would be to do with keywords or other sites ranking higher.

Comment: Hi @closetnoc my traffic from google has continued to drop. Well below the pre-panda 4.2 numbers. I have compared with numbers from June/July that were higher. This is stressing me out a lot now.

Comment: I understand. I am going through some of the same thing. What domain name (can I ask)?

Comment: Yep, of course; sau.com.au (changed domains from skylinesaustralia.com earlier in the year using webmaster tools.)

Comment: I do not see anything obvious I can point to. Your site looks good to me! I do have some activity in my spammer, hacker, scraper database for your host though- looks like compromised systems hacking my site. Ooopppsss... but not your IP address specifically. (for what it is worth) I think that Google is just pinging large sites with a ton of pages largely machine created even if it is user based such as your site seems to be. Mine, for example, reports on spammer, hacker, and scraper activity and yet I get lumped into the whois market. My site is very much a manual process as is yours.

Comment: I have not seen any new information on the net, but I get the feeling that Google is targeting very valid sites that are very large and at least somewhat automated even if it is user based or contains unique data. I have to say I am very disappointed.

Comment: Found this: https://www.mariehaynes.com/algo-changes-and-more/ ... *September 16 (approx) – iOS 9 was released along with a feature to allow users to block ads. It appears that this feature also blocks scripts that track analytics. If you see a drop in Google Analytics traffic around this time, compare your mobile traffic to desktop to see if there is a big difference. It may be that you’re not actually seeing a traffic drop, but that visits from iPhones and iPads are no longer being tracked.* Interesting...

Comment: I am so appreciative of your help @closetnoc thank you! That IOS9 change looks very interesting indeed! _I do have some activity in my spammer, hacker, scraper database for your host though_ - where can I see this? I'd like to try and get it sorted.

Comment: There is nothing for you to fix. As I was using some of my tools to check your host/network to make sure it was at least decent when I found some entries in my database. This happens when something like wordpress installed that is not up to date. You are on a decent host! There were probably just a few dozen entries compared to a sucky host which has 10s of thousands of entries of all kinds. I did not mean to alarm you! Sorry for that. I am still looking for reasons why some sites are seeing what you are seeing. It might just be fluctuations in the process. No one is saying anything at all.

Answer (score 2):

I don't trust GWT data as much as I trust analytics data (rank tracking bots/queries show up in GWT data); I trust analytics data (that requires JS) less than I trust server logs.

Check analytics, then cross-reference server logs; is the traffic drop sitewide or page specific?

Check your backlink profile and make sure you haven't lost any significant backlinks.

None of those actions are definitive but they do help narrow the scope of what is going on.

Comment: There is a drop in traffic from Google in analytics also. Search clicks is now down to 167k. There is definitely less traffic coming in.